# Hibernate performance optimization during inserts

Tags: java, database, performance, hibernate

We recently increased the size of one of the arrays that our java application is using and now the performance has degraded significantly.    We are seeing that the performance problem is specifically due to a database insertion done through hibernate.  We are doing a single insertion of a single record and its taking upwards to a minute to complete the insert!  I'm wondering if there is something not configured correctly that would cause this situation and whether there is a ready solution.

Thanks,

Elliott

Comment: We might be able to help if we saw some code.

Comment: What is the database you are using?

Comment: Make series of thread dumps during this minute (jstack -l <pid>) and attach stack traces of the thread that inserts record to database.

Comment: @svaor: Thread dumps will most probably not help here. Hibernate and the issue at hand here are at a higher level. The OP will most probably be able to track down the inneficiency by looking at the queries generated and with the knowledge of how costly interaction with the tables is (based on size, indexes etc).

Comment: @cherouvim I just wanted to check this. Dump series can show place with long activity - hibernate session (e.g. some flush, dirty objects search...), pool (checkout/checkin statement or connection), net (some DB interaction, DB indexes, blocked sessions...), current bussines logic (some calculations or untidy transaction mechanism) or may be something else. Cause the question is uncertain enough...

Comment: @svaor: Yes, for sure they'll help. What I mean is that if the OP looks at the generated queries (e.g are 10k inserts generated within 1 minute?) and knows his schema (e.g are we inserting in a table with 50 indexes?) then he can start from there without having to go low level.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set batch size parameter for your hibernate. That will allow yu to call multiple insert in one DB change.

Also check whether all the inserts happens in the same transaction. Try to e.g. commit each 100 inserts.